# Ways to convert a function statement to a function expression

Tags: javascript

I have been studying IIFE(Immedately-Invoked Function Expression) and understand the general pattern and how it works:

```
(function boo(y) {
  alert(y);
})(2); // call, not a grouping operator, 2
```

In this case:

```
function body(y){
  alert(y);
}(2);
```

The (2) is just a grouping operator,It has nothing to do with invoking the function statement it is the same as:

```
function body(y) {
  alert(y);
}

(2);
```

I don't understand how these two functions create a Function Expression instead of a function statement:

```
2, function () {
  alert('anonymous function);
}();

// OR 

!function () {
  alert('Hello World');
}();
```

How are these two functions acting as expressions? I can see them being anonymous functions, but I don't understand how they are expressions? Why are they being executed instead of throwing some form of a syntax error?

Comment: They are expressions because you're using them as expressions (by invoking them). They're executed because that's what JavaScript was designed to do when you put `()` after a function definition.

Comment: Why isn't it just a grouping operator?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand your question. Why isn't what just a grouping operator? The `()` at the end? It is a function invocation by virtue of the JavaScript standard.

Comment: But in this context function(){}(), the () is just a group operator and not an invocation of the function.

Comment: I suppose, since it doesn't start with the keyword 'function' it is an expression and not a statement with a grouping operator

Comment: Are you confused about the two uses of `()` and how they can mean different things? Well, the first one, like you said, directly succeeds the keyword `function`, so the JavaScript parser will parse it as a grouping operator; the second one does not, so the parser will parse it as a function invocation.

Comment: recommend some article for you. You can read [this](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-5-functions/). When you have read this, you know the answer.

Comment: @HelloWorld: There's no such thing as an empty grouping operator. It would be a function invocation, but `function(){}()` doesn't get that far since it fails with a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, none of your examples are called "function statement". That's a Mozilla-only distinction for syntax that looks like a function declaration, but appears in a statement block.

> In this case:
>
> ```
> function body(y){
>   alert(y);
> }(2);
> ```
>
> The (2) is just a grouping operator,It has nothing to do with invoking
>   the function statement...

Yes, the `(2)` would be a grouping operator because the function *declaration* is hoisted, so the `(2)` doesn't really follow it.

> ...it is the same as:
>
> ```
> function body(y) {
>  alert(y);
> }
>
> (2);
> ```

Yes, the whitespace is ignored.

> I don't understand how these two functions create a Function Expression instead of a function statement:
>
> ```
> 2, function () {
>  alert('anonymous function);
> }();
> ```
>
> // OR
>
> ```
> !function () {
>  alert('Hello World');
> }();
> ```

They're an expression because of the presence of an operators that require expressions for their operand(s). As such, the function becomes the operand, and so is evaluated as the required expression.

So it's merely that when the program is parsed, and encounters for example the `!`, it knows that what comes next must be an expression, and so when it evaluates the `function () {...` that comes after it, it sees that as a valid expression, and so interprets it as such.